# cascading principles in hibernate

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

This has been asked many times but the answers are not very clear.

I have the following in one of my classes. The problem is the generated SQL script does not contain any trace of the cascading logic.

```
 @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    public ClientEntity getClientById() {
        return clientById;
    }
```

This is an extract of the SQL script generated.

```
create table client_access_token (
       ID integer not null,
        EndDate bigint,
        FK_RightID integer,
        Password varchar(255),
        StartDate bigint,
        Token varchar(255),
        Username varchar(255),
        primary key (ID)
    ) engine=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cascading entity state does not have any relation to the generated sql. It just indicates how you want to propagate the state transition from a parent entity to a child. For this purpose, the JPA `javax.persistence.CascadeType` defines various cascade types:

- ALL

  cascades all entity state transitions.
- PERSIST

  cascades the entity persist operation.
- MERGE

  cascades the entity merge operation.
- REMOVE

  cascades the entity remove operation.
- REFRESH

  cascades the entity refresh operation.
- DETACH

  cascades the entity detach operation.

Additionally, the `CascadeType.ALL` will propagate any Hibernate-specific operation, which is defined by the `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` enum:

- SAVE_UPDATE

  cascades the entity saveOrUpdate operation.
- REPLICATE

  cascades the entity replicate operation.
- LOCK

  cascades the entity lock operation.

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) section of hibernate documentation.

So, most likely what you want is `@OnDelete` [cascade](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade-on-delete). While the previous cascade types propagate entity state transitions, the `@OnDelete` cascade is a DDL-level FK feature which allows you to remove a child record whenever the parent row is deleted.

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
@OnDelete( action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE )
public ClientEntity getClientById() {
   return clientById;
}
```

It should generate foreign key with `on delete cascade`.